# How do I manipulate the DOM using node.js? I have done my document.get only to find out node.js doesn't recognize it

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const   express   = require('express'),
        app       = express(),
        path      = require('path'),
        mongoose  = require('mongoose'),
        userGuess = document.getElementById('userGuess'),
        lastResult = document.getElementById('lastResult'),
        numRound  = document.getElementById('numRound'),
        roundDiv  = document.getElementById('roundDiv'),
        correctNum = document.getElementById('correctNumber'),
        startButton = document.getElementById('startButton'),
        gameInputs = document.getElementById('gameInputs'),
        guessSubmit = document.getElementById('submitGuess'),
        health       = document.getElementById('health'),
        easy        = document.getElementById('easy'),
        normal        = document.getElementById('normal'),
        hard        = document.getElementById('hard'),
        labelDifficulty = document.getElementById('labelNum'),
        points          = document.getElementById('points'),
        span            = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0],
        modal           = document.getElementById('myModal'),
        playerNames     = document.getElementById('playerNames'),
        playerName      = document.getElementById('playerName'),
        submitName      = document.getElementById('submitName'),
        cheat           = document.getElementById('cheatMod'),
        resetGame = document.getElementById('resetGame')
```

In my app.js file, I am manipulating a lot of elements, which is coming from an index.html file, connected to the said app.js file as a script.

Is there any way I can accomplish what I'm trying to do here, but on the node.js? I just need to add a database so I can save highscores and player names.

Thank you.

Comment: why do you need to manipulate dom with node?

Comment: I had no idea haha

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bypass nmy problem by just linking my DOM manipulation from a seprate index.js file, instead of manipulating from my app.js which runs my node. Thank you for your help guys.

Answer (score -1):

Nodejs is server-side. It really isn't supposed to use methods from `windows` or

`document`. If you do it will say it's undefined. There is one way and that is to use puppeteer.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer

Keep in mind you must run puppeteer commands asynchronously. But for the basics and to just do what you want to do try:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var x = async(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('<url>');
    await page.evaluate(() => {
    //insert code here like you would in the console in your browser's devTools
    })
    await browser.close();
}
```

Check out the puppeteer documentation here: 
https://pptr.dev/

Comment: Puppeteer is a dev tool for Chrome that uses a Chrome-only protocol

Comment: Thank you. I think I figured out. I was able to just link my index.js to my index.html and use app.js for node, thats why i couldn't do any of the manipulation because i was manipulating on my app.js.